# How do I convert a Json response into a C# object?

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I've added Newtonsoft.Json to my project.

I'm calling the lyric API at https://apiseeds.com/documentation/lyrics with the following code:

```
LyricClient = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://orion.apiseeds.com/api/music/lyric")
};
LyricClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
LyricClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

string url = LyricClient.BaseAddress + "/" + artist + "/" + track;

var result = await LyricClient.GetAsync(url + "?apikey=" + ApiSeedsKey);

if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

and getting a result string with all the fields named and with the appropriate values (formatted for clarity):

```
{
  "result":
  {
    "artist":
    {
      "name": "Marianne Faithfull"
    },
    "track":
    {
      "name": "Broken English",
      "text": "[Verse 1]...",
      "lang":
      {
        "code": "en",
        "name": "English"
      }
    },
    "copyright":
    {
      "notice": "Broken English lyrics are property and copyright of their owners. Commercial use is not allowed.",
      "artist": "Copyright Marianne Faithfull",
      "text": "All lyrics provided for educational purposes and personal use only."
    },
    "probability": 100,
    "similarity": 1
  }
}
```

So far, so good.

However, when I try to convert it into a C# object so I can manipulate/display it in my program I'm not getting any data back.

I've created a `Result` object

```
public class Result
{
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public Track Track { get; set; }
    public Copyright Copyright { get; set; }
    public double Probability { get; set; }
    public double Similarity { get; set; } 
}
```

and the other sub objects with properties to match the names in the Json to hold this data, for example:

```
public class Artist
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

etc.

However, when I call

```
var resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(resultString);
```

I get a `Result` object, but all the properties are set to null or 0.

I've tried making the property names lower case and adding the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes to the classes, but that's had no effect on the results. I've checked for examples and the ones at places like

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/json-serialization-and-deserialization-in-c-sharp/

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to

don't appear to contradict what I've done, but I still can't get it to work. I must be missing something obvious in my class declarations, but I can't work out what.

Comment: You're missing the wrapping Result, like `public class Wrapper { public Result Result { get; set; } }` - usually you can use something like this to validate your structure: https://app.quicktype.io?share=LPwhmMeZvLo6fTrR8NiM

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I could have sworn I tried that and it didn't work, but I've tried it again and it just has.

Comment: Probably neither the first nor the last time something like this happens :)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I don't think that I had the structure quite right when I tried that. I think I'd misnamed one of my objects.